# Why is iCarly always broadcast live?

Tags: icarly

(Note: this question refers to the in-universe web series that the characters host, not the TV show itself.)

Throughout the series, Carly, Sam, and Freddie face a lot of issues due to the live nature of the show. It'd be a lot easier for many iCarly shows to be pre-recorded and released at the scheduled time, barring a few episodes which might require a live audience interaction.

Why are all iCarly shows broadcast live?

Comment: The answer is in your question: "face a lot of issues due to the live nature of the show".

Comment: Completely agree .... a situation comedy usually needs a constant stream of ideas and events to base the comedy around - the writers don't care that the characters are doing it a less professional way.  For an in-universe answer, in 2007-2012 having access to good and inexpensive video editing and storage was more difficult.